# Removing Kernels from grub

Tags: grub2, kernel

My grub has the following versions which I want to remove.

- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.1.0-rc5-next-20150529
- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.1.0-rc5-next-20150529.old
- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.1.0-rc4-next-20150525
- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.0.0-rc6-next-20150402+
- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.0.0-rc6-next-20150402+.old

I tried the following methods to remove:

Using Synaptic tool and I have typed the following commands:

```
uname -r    
dpkg --list | grep linux-image     
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-xyz  
sudo update-grub2
```

Both of the methods failed to remove the kernel versions.

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: @Ron : when the second command was typed only the generic versions are shown not the above mentioned.

Comment: That's because you installed them using dpkg, not apt. You can remove by `sudo dpkg -r linux-image-x.x.x.x-xyz`. But the easiest way is to use synaptic.

Comment: try @Pilot6's suggestion.

Comment: Post the output of `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`, and give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: Got it solved when I used https://www.linux.com/community/forums/fedora/how-to-remove-kernel-source

Answer (score 0):

If your kernel images and headers had been installed from deb packages, not from repositories, you can remove them by

```
sudo dpkg -r linux-image-x.x.x.x-xyz linux-headers-x.x.x.x-xyz
```

But using synaptic is much easier. you will see what are you doing in GUI.